# multiple records on 1 page with InDesign CS6 Data Merge

Tags: adobe-indesign

I am having troubles with getting data imported with data merge to display on one page.

What I need:

1. On the left page I have 'static' info that I will customize myself.
2. On the right page I want a table that is created through data
   merge.
3. When the right page is not sufficiently big enough for all the
   values then indesign has to add another set of these 2 pages. (on the
   right page the table continues, on the left page my 'static' page is
   duplicated)

[image]

Now when I merge the date from my .csv file InDesign creates a whole new 'book' per value in my list:

creates book per value:

[image]

In the data merge menu I can not select 'multiple records per page' this is just greyed out. I can however achieve what I wan't (multiple records per page) in a seperate document with just a single page.

I am still very new to the data merge function in indesign and have no idea if what I'm trying to achieve is possible.

Answer (score 1):

with data merge, indesign generates the whole document for each line, that's why you have to merge your data on one page.

create only one page, merge your data here and after generating merged document you can add the other pages at above and below of the document.

or you can use "inlinemerge" script, search this on google. it doesn't generate a new document.

Answer (score 0):

I think the inlinemerge script Baris Celik mentioned will help you solve your problem. It allows you to create a template within a text frame that the script will repeat for each record. You can read about it on [Indesign Secrets](https://indesignsecrets.com/data-merge-into-inline-anchored-objects-so-they-flow-in-a-story.php). In the article it makes it sound like you have to use anchored objects but works with regular text as well.